# youtube api results

Tags: api, youtube

i am using the below mentioned url to fetch videos from youtube using youtube api request.
The parameters i requested is the author name as **billgeorgeorg** and keyword as **Good Leaders are Authentic Leaders**.

when i received the results i got the total results as 1 but i cannot able to fetch the video id

can anyone help me out to solve this problem

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=json&max-results=10&start-index=11&author=billgeorgeorg&q=Good%20Leaders%20are%20Authentic%20Leaders

Comment: Which framework you are working in? There are several solutions to get the video id from the url

Comment: i have found out the issue sorry for the post actually the start-index should be as 1 instead of 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is multiple results stuff. Do without max-results and start-index. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=json&author=billgeorgeorg&q=Good%20Leaders%20are%20Authentic%20Leaders
And you have it somewhere down.

```
"yt$videoid":{"$t":"r6FdIVZJfzg"}
```

I'm not home so I'm not sure how to touch it... it has multiple double square brackets but try.
If you need multiple video results, then you get the multiple results, take the info and make the single result url for the json and than take the results.
There is a nice JQuery lib on GitHub, I have to search for it. Worked great and it's simple.

Edit: Found it, use this: https://github.com/defvayne23/jTube/ (works perfectly)